# How can I fix this query error with drush sql-sync?

Tags: drush

I crafted my drush/sites/self.site.yml like below* and verified that `drush rsync @prod:%files @self:%files` worked. However, `drush sql-sync @prod @self` results in the following error:

```
  The command "/usr/local/bin/drush sql-query --strict=0 --file=/tmp/termitral_db_20211011_110905.sql.gz --file-delete --uri=drupal --root=/var/www/drupalvm/drupal/web" failed.

  Exit Code: 1(General error)

  Working directory:

  Output:
  ================


  Error Output:
  ================

  In SqlCommands.php line 199:

    Query failed.


  sql:query [--result-file [RESULT-FILE]] [--file FILE] [--file-delete] [--extra EXTRA] [--db-prefix] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-d|--debug] [-y|--yes] [--no] [--remote-host REMOTE-HOST] [--remote-user REMOTE-USER] [-r|--root ROOT] [-l|--uri URI] [--simulate] [--pipe] [-D|--define DEFINE] [--database [DATABASE]] [--target [TARGET]] [--db-url DB-URL] [--notify [NOTIFY]] [--druplicon] [--xh-link XH-LINK] [--] <command> [<query>]
```

On closer look (aka verbose), I noticed this** and I was told on Drupal Slack that `--file` only takes an uncompressed SQL file (I later verified this). So my question is, how can I fix this dreadful error?

*

```
prod:
  host: example.com
  user: user
  root: /data/web/public_html/web
  uri: default
  paths:
   - files: sites/default/files
```

**

```
// Copy new and override existing files at
// /tmp/termitral_db_20211011_103342.sql.gz. The source is
// termitral@termitral.com:/data/web/drush-backups/termitral_db/20211011103342/
// termitral_db_20211011_103342.sql.gz?: yes.

and

The command "/usr/local/bin/drush sql-query --strict=0 --file=/tmp/termitral_db_20211011_103342.sql.gz --file-delete --uri=drupal --root=/var/www/drupalvm/drupal/web" failed.
```

Comment: I remember this issue from one DDEV project and the workaround was to simply check the /tmp directory, because the file gets downloaded but not imported somehow, and then gunzip and import the database from there. `ddev ssh` and there `cd /tmp`, then `ls -lhA` to get the latest database file name, and then `gunzip < test_20210928_110056.sql.gz | drush sqlc`. It's just a workaround though. And only happened in one single DDEV instance. Still not solved, yet.

Comment: Which version of Drush BTW?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. 9.7.3.

Comment: Can you confirm the workaround? That the downloaded database actually exists in the /tmp folder and just the import didn't work?

Comment: It exists in /tmp and import didn't work. It only works if I decompress it.

Comment: Just FYI: " --file=FILE. Path to a file containing the SQL to be run. Gzip files are accepted." from https://www.drush.org/latest/commands/sql_query/

Comment: And finally, this may be a workaround, https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/4319#issuecomment-790558557

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More information about others with the same problem (https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/4319#issuecomment-790558557)

---

There are two ways to solve this:

- Upgrade drush to v10 (better even would be 11)
  (https://www.drush.org/latest/install/#drupal-compatibility)
- Or, patch your current drush using something like the following:

  ```
  diff --git a/includes/drush.inc b/includes/drush.inc
  index a8f356ff8..85d56f617 100644
  --- a/includes/drush.inc
  +++ b/includes/drush.inc
  @@ -352,6 +352,7 @@ function drush_file_is_tarball($path) {
     $supported = [
       'application/x-bzip2',
       'application/x-gzip',
  +    'application/gzip',
       'application/x-tar',
       'application/x-zip',
       'application/zip',
  ```

Good luck!